# Script by using Maven project with TestNG framework

Tags: maven, frameworks, testng, project

Hi i wanted to to this task but I created the scrip ans still got a error and it didn't run properly

Go to https://expedia.com and create a script by using Maven project with TestNG framework for following steps:

i. Click on flights tab

ii. Fill the form to search flight for roundtrip and click on search button

iii. Select round trip flights

v. Switch to other tab v. Click on checkout

vi. Fill the passenger’s information

Home Class:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class HomePage {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(id = "tab-flight-tab")
    private WebElement flightsTab;

    @FindBy(id = "flight-type-roundtrip-label-hp-flight")
    private WebElement roundTripOption;

    @FindBy(id = "flight-origin-hp-flight")
    private WebElement originInput;

    @FindBy(id = "flight-destination-hp-flight")
    private WebElement destinationInput;

    @FindBy(id = "flight-departing-hp-flight")
    private WebElement departureDateInput;

    @FindBy(id = "flight-returning-hp-flight")
    private WebElement returnDateInput;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[@class='btn-primary btn-action gcw-submit']")
    private WebElement searchButton;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void clickFlightsTab() {
        flightsTab.click();
    }

    public void selectRoundTripOption() {
        roundTripOption.click();
    }

    public void enterOrigin(String origin) {
        originInput.sendKeys(origin);
    }

    public void enterDestination(String destination) {
        destinationInput.sendKeys(destination);
    }

    public void enterDepartureDate(String departureDate) {
        departureDateInput.sendKeys(departureDate);
    }

    public void enterReturnDate(String returnDate) {
        returnDateInput.sendKeys(returnDate);
    }

    public void clickSearchButton() {
        searchButton.click();
    }
}
```

Base Class:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class BaseTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected HomePage homePage;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {
        // Set the path to the chromedriver executable
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver");

        // Create a new instance of ChromeDriver
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Initialize the home page
        homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void teardown() {
        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Configuration XML file (testng.xml):

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="ExpediaTestSuite">
    <test name="ExpediaFlightBookingTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.ExpediaFlightBookingTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Updated ExpediaFlightBookingTest class:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ExpediaFlightBookingTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void bookFlight() {
        // Launch the browser and navigate to Expedia
        driver.get("https://www.expedia.com");

        // Click on the "Flights" tab
        homePage.clickFlightsTab();

        // Fill the flight search form for round trip and click on the search button
        homePage.selectRoundTripOption();
        homePage.enterOrigin("New York");
        homePage.enterDestination("Los Angeles");
        homePage.enterDepartureDate("05/20/2023");
        homePage.enterReturnDate("05/27/2023");
        homePage.clickSearchButton();

        // Select round trip flights
        driver.findElement(By.id("filter-ROUND_TRIP")).click();

        // Switch to the other tab
        String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!handle.equals(mainWindowHandle)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Click on the checkout button
        driver.findElement(By.id("checkout-button")).click();

        // Fill the passenger's information
        driver.findElement(By.id("passenger-first-name")).sendKeys("John");
        driver.findElement(By.id("passenger-last-name")).sendKeys("Doe");

        // Add more code to fill in other passenger information if needed
    }
}
```

I did this too.
need to replace ```
"path/to/chromedriver" with the actual path to the chromedriver executable on your system. Also, ensure that you have the necessary dependencies and configurations set up in your Maven project for TestNG

```
but this error showing
```

FAILED: bookFlight
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null

```
Its not running


if you know how to solve ,please say me thank you
```